# 5-star rating for mobile iOS app

Tags: carto, spatial-database, ios, arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios, esri-geotrigger-service

Looking to create a mobile iOS app to collect consumer feedback on 10 separate locations using a 5-star rating system.  There would be a total of 4 questions, each of which would require a separate rating.

I currently have my app set up with a map displaying 10 point features and geofences around each, so that when a user enters the geofenced area they receive a push-notification asking them to complete a survey.  From this point on is where I need some assistance.

I am not sure how to go about creating a 5-star survey that links back to my feature layer so that when results are collected they can be displayed back to the user via callout box when they select a feature on the map.  Also looking for recommendation on where to host my data so that it is best suited for this (i.e. Parse, CartoDB, etc).

Comment: If you've got the map bit working, but are struggling with the 5-star rating bit, I'd say this is the wrong forum on which to ask the question. You should also post the second question about data hosting separately - but note that Stack Exchange is not designed for recommendations, just solid answers

Comment: The irony of your comment is that I tried stack overflow and they recommended this forum because I was working with geospatial data. I have come to the conclusion that help is limited and redirection is prominent. Either way, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Yeah I hear ya - the Stack Exchange experience can be a bit frustrating. Have you tried looking for jQuery plugins, eg [Good Rating plugin](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/744/Good-Rating-plugin-for-jQuery)?

Comment: I have looked into jQuery. In fact I was thinking that I may attempt to build a web based app and use PhoneGap to distribute it for mobile.  Not sure if that is the right route... but it is worth a shot.

Comment: When you asked [your question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372898/5-star-survey-for-mobile-gis-app-ios) you started by saying "I am currently trying develop a mobile app using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK on iOS" but here, where it would have meant much more, you omitted that highly relevant piece of information.  I'll add it as a tag but I think you should overhaul the body of your text to include it too.

Comment: Hey, without a more thorough description of the technology used for the app I can confirm you CartoDB is a great choice for your mapping and visualizations needs. You can rely on [CartoDB platform](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform.html) to store and visualize the data of your [mobile application](http://cartodb.com/industries/web-mobile/).

If you need further functionality you can find services like [Fulcrum](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/data_collection_fulcrum.html) that can be used along with CartoDB.

Comment: So as much as I love CartoDB, I decided to use Parse for my backend server because it allowed for the distribution and collection of data along with the ability to easily leverage the MapKit in iOS for utilities such as driving directions.  My next milestone will be that display of the 5-star rating system within the app.  Thank you to all that responded.